# Accessing my windows partitions under Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: windows, partitioning

I am very new to Linux so today I decided to get on it.I installed Ubuntu alongside Windows 8 that I use, everything on the installation went very smooth I left every option by default. I logged into Ubuntu and I wanted to access my Windows partitions that I had with Music,Movies,Games etc.. And I get this error when I try to open for example my " D:\ " :

```
Error mounting /dev/sda3 at /media/huntix/Shitz bro: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sda3" "/media/huntix/Shitz bro"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda3': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because windows 8 has an enabled hybrid boot by default to make it boot faster. Try disable it using instruction from the link http://www.techulator.com/resources/5201-How-enable-or-disable-Hybrid-Boot-Windows.aspx. You should be able to access your partition.